# How do I get the closest element in the DOM and add an event listener to it

Tags: jquery

Below is my code, the problem with the code is I am trying to get the enter key to work, when the main element "newsletter-sign-up" has data in it, by adding an event listener. The problem is that this "newsletter-sign-up" is present on the base page, but it can also be present in a "modal" that appears randomly. I am told I can use the same "Id" by using the .closest jquery ... but my code keeps getting an error on .addEventListener is not a function. Here is the code:

//============ Key Press event on the Healthy Tips E-Newsletter ======================

```
$(function () {
    $('#sign-up-submit').closest('form').findByName("newsletter-sign-up")
    //    document.getElementById("newsletter-sign-up")
    .addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {         
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("sign-up-submit").click();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears in a modal popup (*which means that you do not know where it will be placed in the DOM*) you need to delegate the event.

Something like the following should do it

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keypress', '#newsletter-sign-up', function (event) {         
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#sign-up-submit").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the enter key works but the text box value isn't found. Thank you though, I appreciate it.